# How can I upload a file with JSON data to django rest api?

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

I am using angular as the front-end scope and Django Rest as the back-end. Now I am facing a situation where I want to create a Model. The structure of a model is really complex in nature, I could use some other simple way outs but using JSON and passing the files with that can really simplify the logic and also make process really efficient.

I am have been trying a lot but none of the ways seem to work.

Can some someone help me with a standard way or tell me even it is possible or not.

This the structure of my Typescript which I want to upload.

```
import { v4 as uuid4 } from 'uuid';

export interface CompleteReport{
  title: string;
  description: string;
  author: string;
  article_upload_images: Array<uuid4>,
  presentation_upload_images: Array<uuid4>,
  report_article: ReportArticle,
  report_image: ReportImage,
  report_podcast: ReportPodcast,
  report_presentation: ReportPresentation,
  report_video: ReportVideo,
}

export interface ReportArticle{
  file: File;
  body: string;
}

export interface ReportPodcast{
  file: any;
}

export interface ReportVideo{
  file: Array<File>;
}

export interface ReportImage{
  file: File;
  body: string;
}

export interface ReportPresentation{
  body: string;
}

export interface UploadImage{
  file: File;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you wanna send data, but if you wanna send data with multipart/data-form, I think you should make small changes to your report structure.

**JSON doesn't supports binary**. So, you can't put files on it. You need to split file and report JSON.

```js
(async () => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  // here's how to send file on multipart/data-form via fetch
  let reportFile = document.querySelector('#file');
  formData.append("file", imagefile.files[0]);
  // here's your report json
  let report = {
    ...
  };
  formData.append("report", JSON.stringify(report));
  
  // send request and upload
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });

  // do something with response
  let responseText = await response.text();
  console.log(responseText)
})();
```

And I see UUID on your frontend code, I think it's better to put that kinda stuff on backend to prevent manipulated request. I think it's better to put complicated stuff, and any server data related on your backend. Just my opinion.

Comment: On my server side `request.POST` is empty. I cannot get other fields such as `request.POST['report']` at the backend.